# URL Button is not populating the fields

Tags: urlhacking

Can someone tell me why my fields aren't being populated other than my subject field? I am trying to clone a task. I created a URL button on Task object. Here is my code:

```
/lightning/o/Task/new?&defaultFieldValues={!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Task.What)),'&WhatId=' + Task.What,'')},
{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Task.Who)),'&WhoId=' + Task.Who,'')},Subject={!Task.Subject},
Priority={!Task.Priority}, Description={!Task.Description}, Status={!Task.Status}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your task subject has a space like 'Dan Subject' that will break. You need to urlencode all the fields that are not Ids or one word values.

Example:

```
/lightning/o/Task/new?&defaultFieldValues=
{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Task.What)),'&WhatId=' + Task.What,'')},
{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Task.Who)),'&WhoId=' + Task.Who,'')},
Subject={!URLENCODE(Task.Subject)},
Priority={!URLENCODE(Task.Priority)}, 
Description={!URLENCODE(Task.Description)},
Status={!URLENCODE(Task.Status)}
```

This might be helpful: [URL Hacking](https://jayakrishnasfdc.wordpress.com/2020/06/07/url-hacking-in-salesforce-lightning/#:%7E:text=URL%20Hack%20is%20a%20custom,child%20records%20created%20from%20parent.)

Comment: Thank you Dan. It worked. I had to modify a little for the picklist values.